# Material Table grouped view add row doesn't show grouped field

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Grouping in material table.
In the group view when I try to add a new row ,  it doesn't show grouped column.

In following example , I am doing column grouping based on "Geography" column.
In the grouped view when I try to "Add" new records ,I don't see Geography field.
However when I remove all grouping , it works as expected.

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from "material-table";

export default function MatTableDemo() {

  const columns = [
    { title: "Geography", field: "geo", defaultGroupOrder: 0, editable: "onAdd" },
    { title: "Prouct Category", field: "prodCat", editable: "onAdd" },
    { title: "Items", field: "item", grouping: false, editable: "onAdd" },
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      geo: "Canada",
      prodCat: "Food",
      item: "Dairy",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      geo: "Europe",
      prodCat: "Food",
      item: "Dairy",
    },

  ];

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Grouped Table"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: (newData) => {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            //handleRowAdd(newData, resolve)
          })
        },
      }}
      options={{
        grouping: true,
        paging: false,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of an easy way to achieve what you are looking for, also I found a few closed or stall issues regarding this behavior on the official repository ([link1](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1092) or [link2](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1949)).
Based on the *Duplicate Action Preview* example at the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions), I found two different workarounds, boths using `tableRef` and `initialFormData` props.

### Remove all grouping applied and create the new row

[image]

I defined a custom `action` that allows removing the applied filters before presenting the addition row. This is done by performing a re-rendering from setting a different `initialFormData` value.

```js
actions={[
          {
            icon: "library_add",
            tooltip: "Create User",
            onClick: (event, rowData) => {
              const materialTable = tableRef.current;
              setInitialFormData({});

              materialTable.setState({
                ...materialTable.dataManager.getRenderState(),
                showAddRow: true
              });
            }
          }
        ]}
```

This works without using `defaultGroupOrder` on column definition and requires at least one column with a `render` prop defined.

```js
const tableColumns = [
    {
      title: "Category", field: "category"
    },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    {
      title: "Password",
      field: "password",
      grouping: false,
      render: (rowData) => (
        <input type="password" value={rowData.password} readOnly />
      )
    }
  ];
```

### Use a default column value while creating the new row

[image]

The same approach as before, but `initialFormData` now may take the value of the category (is taken from `rowData`), so when the *addRow*  is rendered, the field is not shown but the value is set.

```js
actions={[
          {
            icon: "library_add",
            tooltip: "Create User",

            onClick: (event, rowData) => {
              const materialTable = tableRef.current;
              setInitialFormData({
                category: rowData.category // 2nd approach
              });

              materialTable.setState({
                ...materialTable.dataManager.getRenderState(),
                showAddRow: true
              });
            }
          }
        ]}
```

Works with the `defaultGroupOrder` on column definition:

```js
const tableColumns = [
    {
      title: "Category",
      field: "category",
      defaultGroupOrder: 0 // 2nd approach
    },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    {
      title: "Password",
      field: "password",
      grouping: false,
      render: (rowData) => (
        <input type="password" value={rowData.password} readOnly />
      )
    }
  ];
```

The second approach may look better but it's a bit tricky for the user since the *addRow* always spawns as the 'last' or 'first' row of the table.

To avoid rendering the default **add action button ** on the top right of the table, I use a custom action component to overwrite it, like this:

```js
components={{
          Action: (props) => {
            //If isn't the add action
            if (
              typeof props.action === typeof Function ||
              props.action.tooltip !== "Add"
            ) {
              return <MTableAction {...props} />;
            } else {
              return <></>;
            }
          }
        }}
```

Definitely, this solution feels a little bit hacky, but as I said before I think they are workarounds until the feature is included on the main component.  Hopefully, someone can improve over these proposals.

Hope that works for you! Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-grouping-while-adding-or-edting-4v0gd?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I like the first approach as I don't want to add  "Add" option for each row. I also had to preserve the grouping after new row is added. I am currently achieving that by setting the "defaultGroupOrder" using state property.

Comment: Glad to hear that, thanks for the feedback! If it worked for you, please do remember to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I did but since I am new it doesn't reflect here. this message I get when I upvote:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Great! What it's happening is that you can't upvote yet, but you can accept answers (there is no reputation limit for that). So in order to accept an answer,  you have to click the check mark underneath the vote buttons and it will turn green. Image and info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/880603).